# How to get a token from an ASP API in ionic 2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, ionic2

I have created an ASP API and used the option of individual user accounts upon creation. I have registered a User wonderfully and have even check that they exist in the database. The problem comes when I try to request an authorization token from the API for a registered user.

I have this working using postman, and the API responds fine.

Here is the code for calling the API.

```
let body = "grant_type=password" + "&userName=" + credentials.email + "&password=" + credentials.password;
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:59179/token', body, options).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Here is the error message that appears on the console.

```
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 400 Bad Request for URL: http://localhost:59179/token
```

Am I doing anything wrong with this? have I missed something? anything that anyone could give to help me get this working would be a great help and would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the response body?

Comment: Through large amounts of extra testing this only happens when the user enters a password that is incorrect. the only thing I see is what ive shown which is: HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:59179//token